# Why is the clipping rectangle of the parent window the same as the size of the child window?

Tags: c, winapi

I have an app that has a parent window and a tab control child window. The tab control has the `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` class styles. When I resize the parent window, the clipping rect of the parent in `WM_PAINT` is the same as the size of the tab control. This does not happen with child windows that don't have the `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` class styles. Normally when you resize the parent window the clipping rect of the parent window is equal to the uncovered part of the parent window. Why does this happen?

EDIT: Why is the clipping rect for the parent window the size of the whole client area of the parent? I have not specified `CS_HREDRAW/CS_VREDRAW` for the parent class. I want the clipping rect of the parent window to be only the uncovered area when I resize it. From what I understand the child window inherits `CS_HREDRAW/CS_VREDRAW` if the parent window has those class styles. The documentation doesn't say that the parent inherits those styles from the child. If the parent window doesn't have the `CS_HREDRAW/CS_VREDRAW` class styles, but the child does, then does the parent inherit those styles from the child?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
HINSTANCE g_hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hTab;
    static RECT rc;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hTab = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            WCHAR text[70];

            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            wsprintf(text, L"%d, %d, %d, %d", ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, ps.rcPaint.right, ps.rcPaint.bottom);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)text);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        SetWindowPos(hTab, 0, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const TCHAR szClassName[] = L"Appppppppppppp";
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0; 

    g_hInst = hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szClassName, L"App", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 40, 40, 420, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if(!hwnd) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Your parent window doesn't have the `CS_HREDRAW` or `CS_VREDRAW` class styles. Why do you assume that the clipping rectangle would encompass the entire window, when changing its size? Your class registration requested, that you don't want that.

Comment: @IInspectable Exactly! I requested that the parent window not redraw itself by not specifying `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW`, but it still does redraw every time I resize it. I think it has something to do with the fact the the tab control has the `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` styles. What can I do so the parent window doesn't redraw every time I resize?

Comment: Do you really care? Or are you just missing a [WS_CLIPCHILDREN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) window style?

Comment: I know about `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`. I'm trying to solve another problem. What I really wanted to know is why does a child window with `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` cause the clipping rect of the parent window to be the whole size of the parent window client area?

Comment: Because your child window covers the entire parent window's client area, and the behavior you describe is the documented behavior for the `CS_HREDRAW`/`CS_VREDRAW` window class styles.

Comment: From what I understand the documentation says that if the parent window has the `CS_HREDRAW/CS_VREDRAW` class styles, the child windows inherit those styles too. The documentation doesn't say anything about the parent inheriting those class styles if the child window has those styles. In the example I provided only the tab control has the `CS_HREDRAW/CSVREDRAW` class styles.

Comment: The parent doesn't inherit the styles. You are simply describing the documented behavior, but are attributing it to a different window. If the child window has the `CS_[H|V]REDRAW` class styles set, any change in size causes the entire window to be redrawn. That window just happens to cover the entire client area of the parent, and that's why you attribute the behavior to the parent. Use `::InflateRect(&rc, -10, -10);` in your `WM_SIZE` handler to make this easier to see.

Comment: Even if you deflate `rc` by 10 the size of the tab control will still be included in the clipping rect of the parent. Let's say you have a window 300x200. It's client rect will be {0, 0, 300, 200}. Rect of tab will be {10, 10, 290, 190}. If you size the parent 4 pixels to the right the clipping rect of parent will be {10, 0, 304, 200}. The rect of the tab is included in the clipping rect. Normally when you size a parent window with a client rect of {0, 0, 300, 200}  4 pixels to the right the clipping rect is {300, 0, 304, 200}

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` suggestion. I tried it today and it worked properly. I used to think that `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` was only used so the parent doesn't paint the areas covered by the child windows. I didn't know that `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` also gives the correct clipping rect

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your WM_SIZE handler is too late, parts of the main window are already marked dirty.  You'd have to do it earlier, at WM_SIZING time, before calling DefWindowProc().  Which works fine, but with the gritty problem that it is hard to calculate the client area from the proposed new window size.

The simple workaround is to mark the part of the window occupied by the child control as validated:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    SetWindowPos(hTab, 0, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
    ValidateRect(hwnd, &rc);     // <== added
    break;
```